# Как сделать запрос функцией sendto используя прокси?

Tags: python, сокет, proxy

Пишу скрипт который должен будет сделать запрос к сайту. Для этого взял модуль socket, для запроса решил использовать`sendto(data,(url, port))` Но сейчас у меня вопрос, как сделать запрос этой функцией используя прокси? Прокси у меня есть, просто не знаю как их передавать этой функций.

Comment: Вам именно необходимо использовать настолько низкий уровень работы по сети? Вы сами генерируете все заголовки HTTP протокола? Может проще будет через модуль requests?

Comment: Мне необходимо использовать именно модуль socket и функцию sendto

Comment: Тогда механизм при работе с прокси такой - вы соединяетесь с прокси вместо вашего сервера и шлёте ему в заголовке куда он должен переслать то что вы ему пошлёте.

Comment: И да, вот ещё что - sendto не работает с url'ами, там просто (ip)адрес сервера. Вся работа с url'ми - ручками в заголовке протокола http.

Comment: @GrAnd можно ли пример такого заголовка? Спасибо!